# In Eclipse ADT I create a new cpp file and receive "undefined reference" error

Tags: c++, eclipse, reference, undefined, adt

I am using Eclipse on Ubuntu.  I grabbed a working project from a git repository.  The existing .h and .cpp files in the project can be modified, compiled and run fine.

Then, I add new .h and .cpp files to the project using New->other->C/C++->Header File and Source File.  These new files compile but then generate a link error:

`undefined reference to 'MyFunction()'
Type: C/C++ Problem.`

Which to me means that the compiler is compiling them but for some reason is not putting the new .obj files in the right place for the linker.  I looked into making a makefile or looking for the options either in the Project Preferences or Eclipse Preferences to automatically generate makefiles for the new files I add.

Thanks for your help, I am still new to Eclipse while very familiar with Visual Studio and other IDEs.

Answer (score 2):

My friend and I found an answer, although it requires manually editing a file every time we add a .cpp to the project (even though we are adding them via the Eclipse IDE, Eclipse doesn't modify this file)

Open Project in Eclipse.
open (YOUR_PROJECT)/jni/Android.mk

Look for the section called LOCAL_SRC_FILES

and add the path to your .cpp files (it will find the .h's on it's own) manually line by line like this:
`LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \`
`../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \`
`../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp \`
`../../Classes/WelcomeScene.cpp`

with the "\" character at the of the line as a delimiter.
And a wildcard can be achieved like this:
`LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp`
`MY_SOURCES := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes/*.cpp)`
`LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(MY_SOURCES:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)`